# Number of real roots of $P(x) = (x-a)(x-b)(x-c)+a+b+c-3x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

We have been given that $$P(x)=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)+a+b+c-3x$$

where $a\lt b \lt c$, and real. How many real roots does this polynomal have?

As this cubic equation has real coefficients, imaginary roots are paired. So either $1$ or $3$ real roots are there. But how can I find exact number of real root??

I tried finding $P(a) > 0$, $P(c) <0$, which tells there is atleast one real root. Which we already know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $-\infty <a\lt c < \infty $ and $P(-\infty) <0$;  $P(a) >0$ ; $P(c) <0$ ; $P(\infty) >0$. Since the signs alter, you have three real roots.

Comment: Oh I was only so close to answer!

Comment: @egreg in question it is said that $a<b<c$